# Samsung mobile not getting charge when switch on

Tags: samsung, charging

I am using SAMSUNG DUOS2. Its not getting charge when its switched on. But there is no problem in charging when switched off.

Not charging in both I tried USB as well as wall charger.
Android ver : 4.2.2

I suspect it could be virus problem so with the help of antivirus I cleared some thread. Even after the problem still persist.

Pls suggest what could be the problem?

Comment: Enter [safe mode](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-enter-safe-mode-in-the-Samsung-Galaxy-S-Duos-2-GT-S7582) and check . If the behaviour is same, I can't think of anything other than flash stock as next step and even after that it continues then service center is the answer. If it charges fine on safe mode, then flash stock. In any case flashing stock is the only way to rule out OS issues- make sure you take a back up

Comment: @beeshyams You might want to post that as an answer so that it can be accepted if it works.

Answer (score 1):

- Android doesn't need anti virus - see [Is an antivirus really needed for Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/341/131553)
- Malware is more of a threat- factory reset may not help as the malware may have lodged itself in the `/system` partition, which is untouched during factory reset. See [Can a Factory Reset fix Malware Problem?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/6541/131553)

That out of the way, your problem may be due to:

1. User installed applications misbehaving
2. Malware (though I haven't read of any malware doing this yet)
3. OS corruption (of drivers pertaining to charging)

To rule out 1, put your device in [safe mode](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-enter-safe-mode-in-the-Samsung-Galaxy-S-Duos-2-GT-S7582). If the charging behaviour is fine, then you would need to uninstall all installed apps and re-install one by one checking that problem doesn't surface. Painful, yes, to avoid that  jump to steps in  next para

If the problem persists, you have no other option but to flash stock ROM. [Instructions for flashing](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2479206) here. Stock ROM mentioned there is Indian, which should work fine for you or you can download latest stock ROM from [sammobile](http://www.sammobile.com/). Make sure you take a backup though- if your device is not rooted [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/131553) would help else use apps from play store

That should fix your problem, unless it is hardware related (very unlikely)

Comment: Can you explain how  a user installed app and more specifically, a malware would cause charging to be disabled? I'm expecting real world examples/reports, neither speculations, nor opinions. Given that system partition and kernel always loads in read only mode, how would any driver be corrupted at all?

Comment: @Firelord; 1. No real world examples of malware causing this behaviour AFAIK but it isn't impossible- will edit my answer to reflect that. 2. OS driver corruption is not linked to malware issue but is an independent possible cause

Comment: As I said, system partition doesn't mount in read-write mode and the original kernel image remains intact of changes (my earlier comment stating that kernel loads in read only mode is incorrect) so where is the scope of corruption here?

Comment: @Firelord- if you are saying OS is *incorruptible* then I am confused and would like you to link me to a source that it is . I was /am under the impression that it can be corrupted

Comment: Don't be confused. Just provide technical sources or verifiable methods behind your claims. That's all I'm expecting. As it is written, it seems opinion written as a technical fact. :)

Comment: @Firelord- it is my understanding that drivers / OS can go bad. Have no source to *prove*. If you have either way, please do share