# Will a hard reset remove any malicious software/viruses/malware from my Experia X?

Tags: malware, sony-xperia, hard-reset

I suspect my phone is compromised, and if a simple hard reset will fix all potential problems, I'll do that. Will that solve all potential problems? I'm concerned that the guy who just replaced my phone's screen (had my phone's password) installed something dubious. He said he also adjusted or replaced one or two other components, but did not charge for them.

When I got the phone back it was fine, but an hour later when I unlocked it it was reset, no apps, photos, etc, and the keyboard had changed from English to English-&-something-pictographic, maybe Chinese. I restarted the phone and it looks normal again. But the battery is draining at twice the speed it normally does, which leads me to suspect something is happening in the background.

Comment: password is not required for replacing touch screen. boot in recovery mode perform system integrity check. if nothing is modified and bootloader is locked, factory reset will fix your software issues. but bear in mind problem may hardware related

Comment: nevermind, seems sony has no recovery mode. but there is safe mode you can try for few days and compare battery drain

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a Factory Reset fix Malware Problem?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6541/can-a-factory-reset-fix-malware-problem)